# Angular custom filter that returns if the array has the matching string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, foreach, angularjs-filter

I've been scratching my head for awhile to get this right.  I feel like I am almost there but can't get the last piece right to make it work.  Here's what I am trying to do.  I am creating a custom filter that will loop through my json array to see if there's "status" key and if that "status" key contains "SUCCESS" field, it will return all the object that matches that array.  If the "status" key isn't there, then don't show the array object.  I can see that my loop looks correct since it's figuring out which object array contains the key word but when I try to print out my results, I don't see anything.  Please help!

Here's the demo.
https://jsfiddle.net/missggnyc/6r9oophu/20/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="mySessions">   
    <div ng-controller="sessionController">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Session ID</td>
      <td>Session Name</td>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="cs in cSessions | successSessionFilter"> 
      <td>{{cs.id}}</td>
      <td>{{cs.session_name}}</td>          
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('mySessions', []);
app.controller("sessionController", ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.cSessions = [
    {"id":2,"session_name":"BD20","session_description":"","status":["INPROGRESS"]}, 
    {"id":3,"session_name":"CS03","session_description":"","status":["INPROGRESS", "SUCCESS"]},
    {"id":4,"session_name":"MIS99","session_description":"","status":["FAIL","NOTINPROGRESS"]},
     {"id":5,"session_name":"XGY7","session_description":"","status":["SUCCESS", "NOTINPROGRESS"]},
      {"id":6,"session_name":"DCCC2","session_description":""},
        {"id":7,"session_name":"IUOS33","session_description":""}
    ];
}]);
app.filter('successSessionFilter', function(){
        return function(cObj){          
            angular.forEach(cObj, function(value, key){
                angular.forEach(value, function(v, k){
                    //console.log('k is ' + k + ' and v is '+ v);
                    if(k === 'status'){
                        if(v.indexOf("SUCCESS") > -1){ //if it exists
                            //console.log("SUCCESS exists  "+ v.indexOf("SUCCESS"));
                            //console.log(v);
                            return true;
                        }
                        else { //it the status field isn't there, then don't show the object
                            return false;
                        }                       
                    }
                    else 
                        return false;
                })          
            })
    // console.log(cObj);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go

```
app.filter('successSessionFilter', function(){
  return function(items){           
    var filtered = items.filter(function(item){
      if(item['status'] && item['status'].indexOf('SUCCESS') != -1){
        return item;
      }
    })
    return filtered;
  }
});
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/ogycjbkL/

Comment: Wow.. This is what I needed to do.  Thanks for your answer.  Your code is on the point!

Answer (score 1):

Simpler way. Just modify tr ng-repeat to

```
<tr ng-repeat="cs in cSessions | filter:'SUCCESS'"> 
          <td>{{cs.id}}</td>
          <td>{{cs.session_name}}</td>          
</tr>
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/hm4h2esj/

Comment: what if you have "session_name":"SUCCESS" ? then it doesn't work

Comment: I don't think session_name will be SUCCESS as from the given set of data, session_name is alphanumeric. Your method can fail if key name is changed.

Comment: What if the status array was within another array? This method wouldn't work for that case.  Like if the data was   $scope.cSessions = [
    {"id":2,"session_name":"BD20","session_description":"","status":{"mystatus": ["INPROGRESS", "SUCCESS"]};